# Need to identify the latest commit id (sha) from list of commits

Tags: git

I have a configuration file where multiple commit ids are mentioned for single repository. Now I need to identify the latest commit among the list.

1) Identify Latest commit from the commit history?
2) The latest commit should'nt be based on date, it should be based on commit order/history in the remote repo.

Example: A->B->C->D (Here D is the latest commit).

Comment: Those IDs are *hashes*, they aren't guaranteed to have any particular order. A single repository can have multiple branches, so there you can't even be certain there *is* a single "latest" commit. Please give some more context around the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The solution given by @jthill is working fine as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can get only the ones that aren't ancestors of others in the list with

```
git show-branch --independent A B C D
```

and in your example graph that would show only D.  If the graph looked like

```
A---C---D
 \
  B
```

it'd show D and B.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the repository—i.e., all the commits—you can determine ancestry.  Remember that each commit hash ID locates the commit object, and the commit object itself contains the hash ID of its parent commit (or for merges, parent*s*, plural).  But that doesn't necessarily get you the answer you want, depending on what answer you want.

Consider, for instance, the following commit graph with six commit hash IDs (which we shorten to one letter):

```
A   <- B   <- C
 \
  D  <- E   <- F
```

Here the parent of commit `C` is commit `B`; the parent of `B` is `A`; the parent of `F` is `E`; the parent of `E` is `D`; and the parent of `D` is also `A`.

Using the repository and the command line tools, we can perform pairwise tests, such as: "is commit `A` an ancestor of commit `E`?"  The `git merge-base` command implements this directly using `--is-ancestor`, which tests whether the first-named commit is an ancestor of (is reachable from) the second-named commit.  For instance, running:

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor A E && echo A is an ancestor of E
```

would tell us that A is indeed an ancestor of E.

(Technically `git merge-base` provides a "precedes or equals" test, i.e., A ≼ E: if we run this with `A A` or `E E`, it claims that the commit is an ancestor of itself.  We can test identity by comparing the hashes directly so it doesn't matter that much for our purposes here, but it's worth remembering.)

However, this relationship establishes only a *partial order*.  "Is ancestor" does not obey the [trichotomy law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrichotomyLaw.html) and therefore does not produce a [totally ordered set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotallyOrderedSet.html).  So:

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor B E || echo B does not come before E
git merge-base --is-ancestor E B || echo E does not come before B
```

This would tell us that B ⋠ E, and yet at the same time E ⋠ B.

More generally, we can say that the [partial order operator ≼](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialOrder.html) applied to a set of commits provides only a [partially ordered set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartiallyOrderedSet.html).  This is the longwinded (and more mathematically precise) version of [jonrsharpe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990750/need-to-identify-the-latest-commit-id-sha-from-list-of-commits#comment80928002_46990750).  Only in some circumstances—when all input commits are related via their ancestry chains—is there a single total order; only in that case is there really a "latest commit".